# How can a matrix act on a set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Question from a PhD entrance exam

> If $A=$ \begin{bmatrix} 2&-1\\-1&2 \end{bmatrix}
>
> and $X=\{x\in \Bbb R^2:\|x\|<1\}$ where $\|x\|=|x_1|+|x_2|$
>
> Find $AX$.

Now I know that how $\|x\|<1$ looks like.It looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/g09Pd.png

But I dont know what is meant by $AX$ .

How can a matrix act on a set?

Can someone please help me.

**EDIT**

Using @RobertIsrael

The extreme points are $(1,0),(0,1),(0,-1),(-1,0)$

Now by multiplying $A$ with each one of them we   get $A(1,0)=(2,-1)^T,A(0,1)=(-1,2)^T,A(-1,0)=(-2,1)^T,A(0,-1)=(1,-2)^T$

Comment: All the possible vectors $Ax$ where $x$ is in $X$.

Comment: It's the image of $X$ under $A$.

Comment: I would suggest drawing a graph and noting down the transformation of extreme points.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $AX$ is almost certainly shorthand for the set 
$$ \{Ax\ |\ x\in X\} $$
which is the image of the set $X$ under the map $A$.

---

Here are a couple of ideas to get you started on characterizing $AX$. I recommend you work them out on your own --- especially if you plan to be taking a PhD entrance exam any time soon!

- Draw a picture of the action of $A$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. In conjunction with your picture of $X$, this will help you understand what $AX$ will be.
- Characterize $X$ more precisely than simply drawing a picture. One way of doing it is to write elements of $X$ as linear combinations of some set, i.e., specify $v_1,v_2$ such that $X = \{c_1v_1 + c_2v_2\ |\ c_1,c_2\mbox{ satisfy some constraint}\}$.
- Use the fact that $A$ is a linear map to draw conclusions about $AX$ from your characterization of $X$.

Comment: But how can I find Ax in this case?How can I multiply each element of the set X with A

Comment: Hint: what are the extreme points?

Comment: @RobertIsrael; they are $(-1,0),(1,0),(0,-1),(0,1)$

Comment: And what does $A$ do to them?

Comment: @RobertIsrael;I can find what A does to them by multiplying them by A,but what about the middle points in The set?

Comment: @Join_PhD Hint: $A$ is a linear map

Comment: And linear transformations preserve convex hulls.

Comment: Can i ask for one more hint? How did u find a basis of this set?I know the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$ is $(1,0),(0,1)$,How to find a basis here

Comment: @HenningMakholm;Here $X=(x_1,x_2):|x_1|+|x_2|<1$ ,how to prove that A preserves hulls

Comment: $A(t x + (1-t) y) = t A x + (1-t) A y$.